# How to get to the element through JS in iframe? Selenium, Java

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, xpath, nosuchelementexception

So what we have - there's an iFrame on page which shows a preview of previously generated data. I need to get element with text and then get CSS value from it.

Take a look at the DOM here:

[example of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BviAz.png)
xpath to this element looks right to needed element (God save Chrome DevTools!).
But script cannot detect this element.

What I've did:
1 - switched to Iframe where my element is located - successfully.(no more iframe inside this iframe as per screenshot).
2 - tried to find element - NoSuchElementException.

Probably, such issue appears because of this #document thing ?If so - how do I can solve it and get to needed element with script ?

Comment: can you post the code snippet of switching to the frame that resulted in the `NoSuchElementException`?

Comment: public String getCssValues(){
        String cssValue = "font-style";
        PageUtil.switchToFrame(driver, previewFrame);
        return PageUtil.getCssValue(textInPreview,cssValue);

    }

Comment: Please edit your question and add any relevant code or explanations there so that it can be properly formatted and future readers will see all the info in the question and not be required to read all comments to get all details.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you need to wait till the frame to be loaded as given below.

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 90);
driver=wait.untill(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("previewFrame");

WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.TagName("em"));
String fontStyle=element.getCssValue("font-sytle");
System.out.println(fontStyle);
```